# Doctrine MIN() low performance

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have table (~150 columns with ~150k records) and project on Symfony 3 with Doctrine. In project is clasic filter to show results.

If you submit form i collect data in object `$selectedInputOptions` and build query looks like:

```
$query = $repository
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.idkatcountry', 't.idkatlocality', 't, MIN(t.price) AS priceFrom'......);

if(count($selectedInputOptions->getCountry()) > 0)
   $query->andWhere('t.idkatcountry IN (:idkatcountry )')->setParameter('idkatcountry ', $selectedInputOptions->getCountry());


if(count($selectedInputOptions->getLocality()) > 0)
   $query->andWhere('t.idkatlocality IN (:idkatlocality )')->setParameter('idkatlocality ', $selectedInputOptions->getLocality());
```

price column have `decimal(15,2)` datatype

Before i have in `$repository->select('t.price')` and everything was OK but after change this to `'t, MIN(t.price) AS priceFrom'` query execution time was increased +40% and in few cases (any input in form be blank = checks all records) +900%.

So my questions:

How i can cut execution time? (Is there some idexes for this?, Will help change datetype range let's say to decimal(6,2)?)

And bonus question :) Table has ~150columns but query for filtering using ~10-15 columns can i set some type of index for quicker selects?

### EDIT:

- changed column price to `ineger` - did not help
- added index to column pricte - did not help

### SOLUTION!

It was little mistake in select parameter using `MIN()`.

Insted of:

`'t, MIN(t.price) AS priceFrom'`

I used:

`'MIN(t.price) AS priceFrom')'`

Because `t` takes ALL columns (~150 in my case) and I didn't notice this... So now is everything OK and time is normal.

Comment: What fields are you filtering on and what are their corresponding types? And, do you have fallbacks for the blank fields? Or are they all going to be like a generic LIKE clause?

Comment: I was find solution (updated question) but thank for comment

Answer (score -2):

Here you can do one thing, stop loading unwanted data in entity, by using unset in jsonSerialize() method.